# Multiple if statements with array in JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using the following JQuery code:

```
    (function($) {
  "use strict";

  $( document ).ready(function() {

      var normalPrices = jQuery('.price-range .price .price')
      .map(function() {
        return parseFloat(jQuery(this).text().
          replace(/[^0-9\.]+/g, ""), 10);
      }).get();    



    if (normalPrices[0] < 300) {

      var ifcBalance = normalPrices[0] / 18;
      var m = parseFloat(ifcBalance).toFixed(2);      
      $('div.ifc-balance-div1')
      .html('<p class="dynamic-badge-txt">Only £' + m + ' a month*</p>');
    } 

    else {
      $('div.ifc-balance-div1').hide();
    }



   if (normalPrices[1] < 300) {

      var ifcBalance2 = normalPrices[1]/18;
      var m2 = parseFloat(ifcBalance2).toFixed(2);       
      $('div.ifc-balance-div2')
      .html('<p class="dynamic-badge-txt">Only £' + m2 + ' a month*</p>');
    } 

    else {
        $('div.ifc-balance-div2').hide();
    }    



   if (normalPrices[2] < 300) {

      var ifcBalance3 = normalPrices[2]/18;
      var m3 = parseFloat(ifcBalance3).toFixed(2);      
      $('div.ifc-balance-div3')
      .html('<p class="dynamic-badge-txt">Only £' + m3 + ' a month*</p>');
    } 

    else {
        $('div.ifc-balance-div3').hide();
    }    



  });


})(jQuery);
```

And using `normalPrices[0]`, `normalPrices[1]`, `normalPrices[3]` etc I am trying to set if statement that will show the relevant div element only if the Price is higher than 300. Setting it up as using the code above pick up only the first div and hide the rest two. The interesting thing here is that the first div is not even greater than 300.

The html that I am getting the price is dynamic but static representation would look like this:

```
    <div class="price-box">
    <p class="old-price"><span class="price-label">Was</span> <span class=
    "price" id="old-price-12121"><span class="price"><span class=
    "currency">£</span>399</span></span></p>
    <p class="special-price"><span class="price-label">You Save</span>
    <span class="price" id="price-excluding-tax-12121"><span class=
    "price"><span class="currency">£</span>50</span></span></p>
</div>
<div class="price-range">
            <span class="price-label">From </span>
        <span class="price"><span class="price"><span class="currency">£</span></span></span>
</div>
```

Please note that I have three containers with the same classes and structure as the above

I have the bad feeling that I am not referring correctly to the different `normalPrices` entries in my array. Can anyone help?

Comment: _show ... if the Price is higher than 300_ Your else statement hides the div when `normalPrices[x] >= 300`.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp that is exactly what I want to do but not for all of them in a way that If one of them is less than 300 and the rest are over 300 I still want to show the other over 300

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Number(when using arrays, its always recommended to iterate on the array using a loop statement. Your code test if this works :

```
(function($) {
  "use strict";
  $( document ).ready(function() {
    console.log("load called");
    var oldPrices = jQuery('.old-price .price .price').map(function() { return parseFloat(jQuery(this).text().replace(/[^0-9\.]+/g, ""), 10);}).get();
    var specialPrices = jQuery('.special-price .price .price').map(function() {return parseFloat(jQuery(this).text().replace(/[^0-9\.]+/g, ""), 10);}).get();
    var normalPrices = jQuery('.price-range .price .price').map(function() {return parseFloat(jQuery(this).text().replace(/[^0-9\.]+/g, ""), 10);}).get();    


    for ( var  i=0 ;i < normalPrices.length ; ++i ){
        if (Number(normalPrices[i]) < 300) {
          var ifcBalance = Number(normalPrices[i]) / 18;
          var m = parseFloat(ifcBalance).toFixed(2);      
          $('div.ifc-balance-div' + (i+1) ).html('<p class="dynamic-badge-txt">Only £' + m + ' a month*</p>');
        } 

        else {
          $('div.ifc-balance-div'+ (i+1)).hide();
        }
    }
  });
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: the reason why I am using newPrice[0], newPrice[1], newPrice[2] is because when converting the strings into float and getting them into array I need to make sure that if the now price of the first element is under 300 then it wont show on the 1st element.

Comment: i have updated the code wrapping the normalPrices[i] with the Number() function if i understand your comments @ND

Comment: I got the logic and looks great... however it cant make the calculation from var ifcBalance = normalPrices[i] / 18;

Comment: updated, please try again.

Comment: What did you update as it it giving back the same result. It does appear on all three of them even though there are not all of them less than 300

Comment: where do you use the class `price-range` in your html, i cant see it in the snippet you are using. maybe you should use  var normalPrices = jQuery('.old-price .price .price')

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94655/discussion-between-n-d-and-max).

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're just changing array subscripts and ID values between each `if`, so why not a loop?

```
for(i = 0; i < max; i++) {
   if (normalPrices[i] < 300) {

      var ifcBalance = normalPrices[i] / 18;
                                    ^---
      var m = parseFloat(ifcBalance).toFixed(2);      
      $('div.ifc-balance-div' + (i+1)).html('<p class="dynamic-badge-txt">Only £' + m + ' a month*</p>');
                             ^^^^^^----
    } 

    else {
      $('div.ifc-balance-div' + (i+1)).hide();
                                ^^^------
    }
```

Comment: the above code is not working. The logic I am following here is :Convert the now price in float > check if it is bigger than 300 than show message. Otherwise do hide the html